# How to substitute into function with dummy argument in Maple?

Tags: maple

In maple, I define a function H(x,y) as below

```
H := U(x, y) + U(3*x, y);
```

And then I try to decompose U(x,y) to x*f(y) and then get the corresponding H(x,y), so I do the following

```
subs(U(x, y) = x*f(y), H);
```

Maple gives me
x*f(y) + U(3*x, y)
But what I expect is
x*f(y)+3*x*f(y) or 4*x*f(y)

[enter image description here][1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQb1a.jpg
What should I do?

I expect Maple to do further substitution to give the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple did what you instructed it; it literally substituted for `U(x,y)` in the expression assigned to `H`.

Your described expectation does not match literal substitution for `U(x,y)`. Rather, your description is that of getting the expression re-evaluated with some operator replacing `U`.

```
H := U(x, y) + U(3*x, y);

     H := U(x, y) + U(3 x, y)

eval(H, U = ((a,b)->a*f(b)));

              4 x f(y)
```

Note that does not guard against calls to `U` having less than the expected two arguments.

```
G := U(x, y) + U(3*x, y) + U(z) + (Ua,b,c):

eval(G, U = ((a,b)->a*f(b)));
Error, invalid input: unknown uses a 2nd
argument, b, which is missing
```

Here is another way, that only acts on function calls to `U` which have exactly two arguments -- and leaves others alone.

```
evalindets(H, And(specfunc(U),
                  satisfies(t -> nops(t)=2)),
           t -> op(1,t)*f(op(2,t)));

              4 x f(y)

evalindets(G, And(specfunc(U),
                  satisfies(t -> nops(t)=2)),
           t -> op(1,t)*f(op(2,t)));

      4 x f(y) + U(z) + (Ua, b, c)
```